# How to customize Excel Ribbon at runtime

Tags: c#, ribbon, netoffice

Is there a way to use Netoffice to customize Office/Excel Ribbon at runtime, My concern is that I am trying to make plugin-able addin that adds button to Ribbon based on available action of my plugins.
I actually created my tab using XML but I can't figure out how to add items dynamically at runtime.

Thank you for help.

Comment: haven't used Netoffice but layout in Excel dynamically with Excel DNA was nutoriously hard for me.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know [netoffice](https://netoffice.codeplex.com) doesn't provide anything for customizing the Fluent UI. The Ribbon UI is a static thing from its birth. The only possible dynamism is callbacks. For example, you can define a dynamicMenu which provides the **getContent** callback (gets an XML string that contains the contents of this dynamic menu).

Read more about the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

Also you may find these articles helpful:

- [Chapter 11: Creating Dynamic Ribbon Customizations (1 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548010(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Chapter 11: Creating Dynamic Ribbon Customizations (2 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548011(v=office.12).aspx)